# Google analytics with user-id login and logout

Tags: swift, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I use google analytics in my mobile app. I want to send data about my users ids.
In Swift it looks like

```
let my-user-id = 22 
let GATracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
GATracker.set(kGAIUserId, value: "\(my-user-id)")
```

So is it ok that i put this code in my login action? 
And also i want to know - how can I tell goole that user is logged out?